# Entanglement entropy (EE) of a non-contiguous subsystem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I know how to calculate EE for a contiguous sub-system using Schmidt decomposition aka SVD. Algorithm 9 on page 11 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.12757). Is there any similar SVD algorithm of [restructuring](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/understanding-entanglement-with-svd) the wave function matrix when the subsystem is not contiguous? One could calculate the partial trace but is there any other way that can be used for many-body numerical calculations?

In a 1D system of $L$ degrees of freedom(e.g. bosons) , the above SVD method assumes a subsystem $A = \{j| 1\leq j \leq l_A\}$. The subsystem I am interested in is $A = \{j| 1\leq j \leq x, L/2 \leq j \leq l_A + L/2 -x\}$.

Comment: Your question is lacking detail. How is your wavefunction represented? Otherwise, I don't see why the partition chosen would matter -- you just have to permute the entries in your wavefunction before that (e.g. in MATLAB using reshape(permute(reshape(...)))).

Comment: Are you considering fermionic systems here?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, Wave function is a pure state in many-body basis, in say the occupation number basis. Why do you permute? Is it to make the sub-system contiguous after permuting? I don't full understand this. Could you may be explain with an example. I will make my question a bit more detail.

Comment: @BySymmetry Right now I am only dealing with bosons.

Comment: @Levitt Indeed, to make it contiguous. I still don't understand the question -- EE is obtained from the SVD, after grouping the indices for the two parts as row and column indices. Without more details on how you compute the EE, it will be hard to give a succinct answer.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I am a bit confused about how to restructure the wave function into a matrix when the sub system is not contiguous. After this step I know how to calculate EE from that, using SVD decomposition of the matrix. Now, I have some idea on how to proceed. I will give it a shot and may be post in next few days.